# Solving diophantine equations

Tags: diophantine-equations, problem-solving, prime-factorization

So the equation I am trying to solve is $x^2=y^4-77$

So far I have rearranged and factorised the equation to get:
$$(y^2-x)(y^2+x)=77$$

But I am really unsure of how to solve it from here. Thanks in advance

Comment: **HINT**: Express $77$ as a product of prime numbers

Comment: Try to find all solutions of $77=ab$ in integers.

Comment: More or less a duplicate [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195904/integer-solutions-to-x2-y2-33).

Answer (score 1):

$(y^2−x)(y^2+x)=77$

$77 = 7*11$ so $(y^2+x=11)$ and $(y^2-x=7)$

$(y^2+x)-(y^2−x)=2x$ = $11-7 = 4$

Hence $x=2$ and $y^2 + 2 = 11$ so $y=3$

$x$ and $y$ can take negative values as well so range of solutions is $x=\pm 2$ , $y=\pm 3$